# groovy&grails- How to go over array of object?

Tags: grails, groovy, each

I have an array of Person object (person.first person.last).

To find out if the person have first name I have to "run" on the array.

I try the following but I got error:

```
person.eachWithIndex { String persons, i ->
if(persons.first=='')
println(''error)
}
```

How should I manipulate the object array?

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_looping_structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
class Person {
   def first
   def last
}

def persons = [ new Person(first:'',last:'last'), new Person(first:'john',last:'anon')]

persons.eachWithIndex { person, i ->
    if(person.first==''){
      println("error at person in position $i")
    }
}
```

Since you doesn't add more details, I don't know what you're looking for when you say *manipulate object array* so there is some samples:

To manipulate the array objects you can add the statements in the `each` itself, for example to add a `notDefined` as a `first` for person where `first==''` you can use:

```
persons.eachWithIndex { person, i ->
    if(person.first==''){
      person.first = 'notDefined'
      println("first as notDefined for person in position $i")
    }
}
```

To remove the elements where `first ==''` you can use `removeAll` method to remove the undesired elements from the array:

```
persons.removeAll { person -> 
    !person.first
}
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:**

If you want to remove null elements from your list, you can do it with the expression you use in your comment:

```
def persons = [ new Person(first:'pepe',last:'last'), null]
persons.removeAll([null])
println persons.size() // prints 1 since null element is removed
```

However seems that you're not trying to remove null elements instead you're trying to remove elements where all the properties are null, in your case you want to remove: `new Person(first:null,last:null)`. To do so you can try with the follow code:

```
def persons = [ new Person(first:'pepe',last:'last'), new Person(first:null,last:null)]

persons.removeAll{ person ->
    // get all Person properties wich value is not null
    // without considering class propertie wich is implicit in all classes
    def propsNotNull = person.properties.findAll { k,v -> v != null && k != 'class' }
    // if list is empty... means that all properties are null
    return propsNotNull.isEmpty()
}

println persons.size() // prints 1
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: @albciff- in case I have objects which all their properties are null. how can I remove them?

Comment: I tried invitation.removeAll([null]), but it doesn't work